# C# and WPF: Datagrid MouseDoubleClick not firing and sending item

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have attempted to find an answer to this question but to no avail.

I am attempting to realise the following storyboard:

1. User has a DataGrid of items to view
2. User clicks on row with item that has an identifier
3. Window opens with item (using the identifier) values allowing edits

Yet after finding multiple solutions none have been able to help me any further. The MouseDoubleClick seems not to fire upon doubleclicking a row and neither do I get any information whether it does. How can I resolve this?

```
    private void Grid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var SelectedItem = Grid.SelectedItem;
        ItemClass selItem = SelectedItem as ItemClass;
        ItemForm win1 = new ItemForm();
        win1.DataContext = SelectedItem;
        win1.Show();
    }
```

It's one of the many "simple issues require reinventing the universe" situations i've come across, sadly.

Edit: The next problem I came across is that regardless of what is done, SelectedItem will always return null. How can I resolve this? In the DataGrid XAML I have already added `SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"`

Comment: If you debug on the first line of Grid_MouseDoubleClick it doesn't ever get to it? Can you show how you subscribed to the MouseDoubleClick event?

Comment: Are you sure that it's not the `if (Grid.SelectedItem == null)` statement that prevents it from opening? I tried this now and it seems to be working (unless you disable hit test via `IsHitTestVisible` property)

Comment: @BlakeThingstad It turns out the subscription was indeed the cause as I never issued a handler for the event. Whoops.